# Call a function by name in Unity

Tags: unity

This might be a bit misplaced but is there a way to call a function by name in Unity?

I've tried Invoke(string, float) but that doesn't accept parameters.  I've tried StartCoroutine but that requires a yield return new statement.  I've also tried reflection, like this:

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(TheCommandString);
theMethod.Invoke(this, userParameters);
```

But this doesn't even compile giving an error of `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`
 and I don't really know why.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You'd have to tell us the errors you're seeing if you want to know why [your reflection code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/540075/737147) isn't working.

Comment: @Byte56 Is this OK?  I already stated what I've tried... what else do I need to put?

Comment: Have you looked up why programs return a null reference exception generally speaking? Then looked for that situation in your own code? You're trying to use some variable that hasn't been assigned to, or it's being assigned null. Attach the debugger and check it out.

Comment: Look... the point is that I copied the code exactly from the post, and it hasn't really worked.  I checked my code thoroughly for the problem and there is no problem.  The problem is with that particular statement.

Comment: Not all code found on the internet can just be pasted into your existing code and it'll work. As I said, you need to attach the debugger, find out where the problem is. Which variable is null? Why is it null? Did you look at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6(v=vs.110).aspx)? Did you know that `GetMethod` returns null if the method isn't found? Are you calling `GetMethod` on the right type? Are you searching for the right method? You haven't given us enough information to answer your question, so it remains closed.

Comment: You need to use reflection, either using the `dynamic` keyword or `GetType`, A nullreference is expected when you don't find a method and then try to call it. GetMethod(string) only searches for public methods and frequently fails due to typos.

Comment: You can use [SendMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html) to invoke a method by name in Components/MonoBehaviours attached to a GameObject, passing up to one argument. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do / what feature it's serving though, it's hard to know if this is an appropriate solution for your use case. I've also written about [more involved uses of reflection in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/141089/39518), if that may be useful.